# ZXing recognition speed

Tags: android, zxing

i'm building an android application and i'm using ZXing to implement QRCode scanning but the speed to recognize a code in my app is too diferent from the ZXing  [android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android).

The ZXing Team's app recognizes the code almost instantly, but in my app it takes several seconds and i have to move the camera around to get it working, both tested on the same phones.

How or what shoul i tweak in my code to make it work as fast as the playstore app?

I followed this simple tutorial and have a scanning activity as described [here](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) in the "Simple Usage" section.